# How to list all the folder in a folder and exclude a specific one

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Let's say I have a folder like this:

my_folder

====my_sub_folder_1

====my_sub_folder_2

====my_sub_folder_3

====exclude

I would like a command that return a string like this :

> ["my_sub_folder_1", "my_dub_folder_2", "my_dub_folder_3"]

(Notice the exclusion of the excude folder)

The best I could is :

```
ls -dxm */
```

That return the following.

> my_sub_folder_1/, my_dub_folder_2/, my_dub_folder_3/

So I'm still trying to remove the / at the end of each folder, add the [] and the "".

If it's possible I would like to do that in one line so I could diretly put in a shell variable, other wise I will put it in .sh file that will return the string I'm trying to build.
(I don't know if the last part is really possible).

Comment: @RobertReynolds: If you had Zsh, you could get a list of the directories without `exclude` by `dirlist=($(echo ${$(echo *(/))#exclude}))`, but AFIK, bash does not have such a neat feature. So in bash, you would have to loop over the entries in your folder and select the desired ones manually.

Comment: I said exclude was a folder. The rule is to exclude the folder named exclude.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are executing the script in the directory where `my_folder`
belongs, how about:

```
while IFS= read -r -d "" f; do
    ary+=("$f")
done < <(find "my_folder" -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d -not -name "exclude" -printf "\"%f\"\0")

(IFS=","; echo "[${ary[*]}]")
```

**[Explanations]**

- `-printf` option to `find` command specifies the output format. The format `"\"%f\"\0"`
  prints the filename (excluding leading directory name) wrapped by
  double quotes and followed by a NUL character `\0`.
- The NUL character is used as a filename delimiter and the filenames
  are split again in the `read` builtin by specifying the delimiter
  to the NUL character with `-d ""`.
- Then the filenames (with double quotes) are stored in the array `ary`
  one by one.
- Finally `echo "[${ary[*]}]"` command prints out the elements of `ary`
  separated by `IFS`. The whole output are surrounded by the square brackets `[]`.
- The last line is surrounded by parens `()` to be executed in the subprocess.
  The purpose is just not to overwrite the current `IFS`.

If you save the script in my answer as `my_script.sh`, then you can assign
a variable `MY_VAR` to the output by saying:

```
MY_VAR=$(./my_script.sh)
echo "$MY_VAR"
# or another_command "$MY_VAR" or whatever
```

Alternatively you can assign the variable *within* the script by modifying
the last line as:

```
MY_VAR=$(IFS=","; echo "[${ary[*]}]")
echo "$MY_VAR"
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Could explain a bit more what you do ?
In particular the last line.

Comment: @RobertReynolds Thank you for the feedback.  I've updated my answer with some explanations. Hope it helps.

Comment: Very clear ty. From my side I've put this in a .sh file. I would like to return the result variable so I could use it in the next command (which is not in the sh file).
How could I do that.

Comment: The result string looks like a json array and I expect you will execute another command or script by using  the string from within or without the bash script. Can you provide an example of the command invocation for better understanding? BR.

Comment: Yes here is an exemple of what I'm doing now.
At the end of the script you provide I put the last line in a variable named MY_VAR.

Then I call the script doing source my_script.sh.

Then I call I do echo $MY_VAR.

Comment: I've modified my answer accordingly. I hope it will meet your requirement. BR.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205447/discussion-between-robert-reynolds-and-tshiono).

Comment: I do agree. My response may be tomorrow due to the time zone. BR.

Answer (score 1):

In bash this can be done as follows, it's close but it doesn't work in one line.

Change the Internal Field Separator to be a new line rather than a space. This allows spaces in directory names to be ignored.

Then perform the following:

- List the directories, one per line
- Use grep to remove the directory to be excluded
- Iterate over the results:

  - Output the directory name with the last character removed
- Pipe everything to xargs to recombine into a single line and store in $var
- Trim the last , from ${var} and wrap in '[]'

```sh
IFS=$'\n'
var=`for d in \`ls -d1 */ | grep -v exclude_dir \`; do  echo '\"'${d::-1}'\",' ; done | xargs`
echo '['${var::-1}']'
```